# Installing Symfony2 with composer failed on mac os

Tags: php, macos, symfony, composer-php

Trying to install Symfony2 via composer failer.
It'seems to be a access right issue :

cmd : 
composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition /Users/anthonydiniro/WWW/win4u2.com

result:

> Installing symfony/framework-standard-edition (v2.5.0)
>     - Installing symfony/framework-standard-edition (v2.5.0)
>       Downloading: 100%
>
> [ErrorException]
>     copy(/Users/anthonydiniro/.composer/cache/files/symfony/framework-standard-edition/96cf36b581c9cd4827fe8c973080a6db085a49b6.zip): failed to open stream: P
>     ermission denied

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

**Try what jperovic said first!**

otherwise try `sudo composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition /Users/anthonydiniro/WWW/win4u2.com`

If that doesn't work try `sudo chmod 777 -R /Users/anthonydiniro/.composer/cache/`

Answer (score 1):

As always, the first good thing to try if you have encountered an error is to run

```
php composer.phar self-update
```

That will ensure the latest `composer` binaries. Then, run your installation again ;)